# How to continuously read from stdin (not just once input file is done)?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, sys

I have these two scripts:

clock.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

while True: 
    print("True", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

continuous_wc.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def main():
    count = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(str(count))
        count += 1

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And I run them like so:

```
./clock.py | ./continuous_wc.py
```

I'm hoping that it prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Every second is like a clock, because it's counting the lines in the file basically. But it doesn't output anything. Why not?

Comment: You need to flush the stdout buffer in `clock.py`.

Comment: `print("True", flush=True)`

Comment: The problem isn't with reading, it's with writing to a pipe.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. I have updated the question with that suggestion. It still seems not to have any output.

Comment: You should write a newline after the count in `continuous_wc.py`, since you want each number on a different line. That will also solve the problem, since output is line-buffered.

Comment: Why are you using `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`, instead of `input()` and `print()`?

Comment: I think what Barmar is suggesting is that you also need to flush the output from `continuous_wc.py`.

Comment: You could try `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ; ./clock.py | ./continuous_wc.py`

Comment: If your Python is 3.6 or newer, you can write more elegantly (and with the desired newline): `sys.stdout.write(f"{count}\n")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `print(x, flush=True)` you must also flush after `sys.stdout.write`.

Note that the programs would technically work without flush, but they would print values very infrequently, in very large chunks, as the Python IO buffer is many kilobytes. Flushing is there to make it work more real-time.

```
sys.stdout.write(str(count))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using everyone's advice, this is what I have now (which works):

clock.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

while True:
    print("True", flush=True) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

continuous_wc.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def main():
    count = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print(count, flush=True, end='\r')
        count += 1

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I had to use `flush=True` in both the write and the read scripts. However when using `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`, I was able to skip this and it worked. Thanks @Mark Setchell. Additionally, I am using `print` and `stdin` but it seems `fileinput.input` works as well.